# Help needed with differential equation which does not seem to fit any type

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve the following differential equation:

$$dy/dx=x^2+2xy+y^2+2x+2y$$

I am not sure which approach to use since the equation does not seem to be separable or exact or homogeneous. What am I missing?

Comment: The right hand side depends only on the combination $x+y$

Comment: That is true, but how do I use this fact to solve the equation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the differential equation can be written as

$$
\frac{dy}{dx}=(x+y)^2+2(x+y)
$$

I would do $u = x+y$ which in turn will give us

$$
\frac{du}{dx} = \frac{dy}{dx}+1
$$

Substituting in the original equation should give

$$
\frac{du}{dx} -1 = u^2+2u \Rightarrow \frac{du}{dx}=1+2u+u^2 = (1+u)^2
$$

Can you complete it from here?

Comment: Yes, thank you!

Comment: No problem. If the question has been answered for you, be sure to click on the 'green tick' just below the voting arrows of the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Naji also $dy/dx=(x+y+1)^2-1$ , setting $u=x+y+1$?  You end up with $\frac{du}{dx}=u^2$